# How to add each element of a tuple or list by a fixed value?

Tags: python, pygame, tuples

I have a tuple representing RGB color. My goal is to make it go from black `(0, 0, 0)` to white `(255, 255, 255)` in one second by adding a fixed value in each frame. How would I code this in a function?

Here's the update function:

```
def update(self, dt):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000
        if now - self._spawn_time >= BALL_WAIT_TIME: 
            self.rect = self.calcnewpos(dt)
            self.handle_collision()
        else:
            # ANIMATION HERE
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable. It's not really clear how you propose changing the value of one.

Comment: +1. For me: wrong assumptions, valid question. Could you make it more clear what do you mean by 'make it go'? The title is also a bit unclear to me: maybe *'How to add a fixed value to each element of a list'* was your question? (As it stands, it doesn't make sense to me, I suspect wrong English. While 'elements' could be 'added' to something, but not 'by' anything - except, 'by a human', or 'by a function', etc., but I think it's not what you meant).

Comment: @naxa I meant I wanted the tuple to increase in value until it reached white (255, 255, 255).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your tuples are just repeating the same number, just use a range loop and create the tuple from scratch:

```
for i in range(256):
    rgb = (i, i, i)
```

There is no need to add up here.

Alternatively, calculate `i` from the frame. 30 frames in a second? Divide 256 by 30 to get a step size, then use the frame number:

```
step = 256 / 30.0
value = int(frame * step)
rgb = (value, value, value)
```

Comment: I understand range returns an iterator. Woudn't it be expensive to call it every frame?

Comment: @Jovito: Since you didn't specify *how* your animation works I gave you two angles. The range idea is when you drive the animation with the loop itself. The point is that you generate the RGB tuple from scratch for each frame.

Comment: Another problem with this is that the values could get greater than 255. It doesn't answer the question as it is.

Comment: @Jovito: you didn't post code before. I was demonstrating *principles*. You do need to do some work yourself! How about working out how many frames you need and taking the step idea from that?

Comment: @Jovito: you have pygame ticks; those count milliseconds. If you need to animate for one second, you'll have 1000 ticks to work with. `255.0/1000` gives you a step size per tick. Calculate the RGB values from that.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand what's wrong with this question. Maybe I didn't explain myself very well.

Comment: Your original question was very much a 'give me the code'; you didn't include any sign of effort on your part. That often attracts downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seriously concerned with performance per frame, you can pre-allocate all the tuples you will need.

So why not make a dictionary of colors for whatever you're trying to do?

```
# Pre-animation allocation
colors = {}

for i in xrange(256):
    colors[i] = (i,i,i)
# Divide 256 by frames per second
step = 256 / 60
# current RGB value
RGB_val = 0

# During animation, suppose loop iterates 60 times per second
while True:
    # During update
    RGB_val += step
    color = colors[min(RGB_val,255)]
    # Draw to display surface
```

You will have the highest performance if you preallocate your tuples at the beginning of whatever you're trying to do rather than trying to generate your tuples as your code is flipping quickly through frames. Python can easily load and store 256 tuples of 3 elements in memory and quickly flip through them with minimal performance cost in the middle of your animation loop.

Comment: Generating a 3-element tuple from simple arithmetic is going to perform equally well, actually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so. my method switches the binding of the name `color`. your method generates tuples every frame. Creating tuples (or any object for that matter) is costly in Python. Switching what a name points to is not, especially if the name is in a dictionary which would be stored in the local scope (Python will use registers for the dictionary and looking up a value in a dictionary is blazingly fast because of Python's hash function). You can use `timeit` to test if you don't believe me on how slow creating tuples/lists is.

Comment: Tuples are cached, and creating of short tuples is relatively cheap, actually. Looking up objects in a dictionary does require calculating the hash. Calling `min()` requires a global lookup and a stack push and pop. That all counts *too*.

Comment: I am not saying that my version *will* be faster, you'd need to run actual `timeit` trials there. But don't go by 'dictionary lookups are fast' either, not when you are doing calculations to create key *too*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that `__hash__(x)` where x is an integer type in Python simply returns x itself. So there is really not much calculation if the keys are all `int` types.

Comment: `hash(int)` is indeed the integer for most values. But then you still need to run the hash algorithm to fit that in the hash table, including handling collisions and testing for equality. It is not 0 cost. It is an almost constant cost, which is much better than variable cost, but there is a cost. Creating a tuple is also a constant cost. You need to use actual timing trials to figure out which one is going to be cheaper; both approaches are O(1) in complexity.